# How do I install stable SopCast-Player in Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, sopcast

What is the best and the easiest way to install a working and stable Sopcast-Player in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So, let's install `SopCast-Player` easy and fast right away. For this we need:

**1**. Firstly, update `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**2**. gdebi installer:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

**3**. install python-glade2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-glade2
```

**4**. Download and install `sp-auth` with `gdebi` installer, just right click on a file and choose install with `gdebi`.

[Download sp-auth 32bit version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9jmwmzzfy36yhey/sp-auth_3.2.6~i386.deb?dl=0)

[Download sp-auth 64bit version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rya8u65v3slpqxf/sp-auth_3.2.6~amd64.deb?dl=0)

**5**. Download and install `SopCast-Player` with `gdebi` installer.

[Download SopCast-Player 32bit version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nloa1tc72qvv06r/sopcast-player_0.8.5~i386.deb?dl=0)

[Download SopCast-Player 64bit version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5l1dr1rnmtsrv1/sopcast-player_0.8.5~amd64.deb?dl=0)

Type `sopcast-player` in terminal or type in Dash Launcher Search and hit it.

Enjoy!